# CSS Centering floating divs

Tags: html, css

This centering div problem would never go away! i need help...
for some reason i never managed to center multiple floating divs, even with the whole internet having the answer..!! (am i the problem?)

```css
     .middle {
       margin-top: 40px;
       border-radius: 10px;
       width: 100%;
       background: #ffffff;
       bordder-radius: 10px;
       border: thin solid #777;
       box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
       padding: 5px 10px;
       text-align: center;
       overflow: hidden;
       display: inline-block;
       text-align: center;
     }
     .vidtyp {
       float: left;
       padding: 5px;
       margin: 30px 30px;
       border: thin solid #BBB;
       border-radius: 10px;
       display: inline-block;
       box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
     }
     .vidtyp img {
       width: 250px;
       height: 250px;
     }
     .vidtyp:after {
       clear: both;
       content: "";
       display: table;
     }
```

```html
<div class="middle">
  <br>

  <div class="vidtyp">
    <img src="">1
    <br>Movies</div>
  <div class="vidtyp">
    <img src="">2
    <br>Series</div>
  <div class="vidtyp">
    <img src="">3
    <br>Anime</div>
  <div class="vidtyp">
    <img src="">4
    <br>Fun</div>
  <div class="vidtyp">
    <img src="">5
    <br>Fun</div>

  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

can someone please point my problem here? i tried everything and im on the verge of quitting CSS and going back to tables. i managed to center 1 div, but never many floating... almost every website i visit says the same thing.. yet i never made it.

Help please!

Comment: You're floating all of the `.vidtype` to the left.  Are you expecting all of these to be stacked in the center?  They won't if you float them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove `float: left;` from `.vidtype` they will center themselves.

```css
.middle
{
    margin-top:40px;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:100%;
    background:#ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: thin solid #777;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.vidtyp
{
    padding:5px;
    margin: 30px 30px;
    border: thin solid #BBB;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
.vidtyp img
{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
}
.vidtyp:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

```html
 <div class="middle">
     <div class="vidtyp">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
         <p>Movies</p>
     </div>
     <div class="vidtyp">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
         <p>Series</p>
     </div>
     <div class="vidtyp">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
         <p>Anime</p>
     </div>
     <div class="vidtyp">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
         <p>Fun</p>
     </div>
     <div class="vidtyp">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
         <p>Fun</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

---

Also you have some errors in your code which I've fixed.

1. `<img>` tags must always include a closing `/` and an `alt=""` attribute, like this `<img src="pathtoimage.jpg" alt="" />`.

   If you're not certain if your HTML is correct, you can run it through the [W3C Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) to check and see.
2. Don't use `<br>` to create a new line, instead wrap the contents in a block element, such as a `<p>` or a `<div>`.  Block elements will automatically be displayed on a new line.
3. `bordder-radius:10px;` is a misspelled CSS attribute and is not valid.  It should be `border-radius:10px;`
4. Lastly, be sure to indent and format your code correctly, it really makes it easier for you and others to work with.  Pretty and clean code is what you should always aim for if you're planning on asking others to help you with it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9my9Lbon/2/

Comment: MY HERO!!!! i know i will never forget this... EVER! i was fed wrong information then. :( thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

> im on the verge of quitting CSS and going back to tables.

**First off, do not do that^**

You need to surround your floated divs in another div.  Then set the surrounding div to have `margin: 0 auto;`

Also, stop using breaks to push things down.  That is what margins are for.

If you are having a difficult time understanding CSS and HTML [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/) is free and will help you learn in no time.

Best of Luck!

Comment: i added a div.. didn't work.. it is already inside a div and it is not working, but thanks for the link :D

Comment: @bakriawad I mean a div around everything as a container

Comment: i already do have it.. but the page is big and has php properties and other stuff... it is not good to paste the entire page here. :)

Comment: @bakriawad gotcha, glad you fixed it no thanks to me ;)